# Evento onload para iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, javascript-eventos

#### Questão

Digamos que em meu site eu tenha um `iframe` reservado para carregar uma possível pagina externa, e este `iframe` esteja com `display:none`, como eu poderia criar em `callback` para disparar ao final no carregamento desta pagina, para realizar um `display:block`?

#### Nota

Lembrando que eu poderia querer conteúdo completo, o que inclui o carregamento das imagens, ou parcial apenas do HTML. Seria o mesmo evento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes usar o evento [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load), que vai ser disparado quando todos os recursos forem carregados:

```js
const iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');

window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log('Está tudo carregado');
    iframe.style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
iframe {
 display: none; 
}
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gQghzrNo68s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/load)

Para disparares o evento quando acontece só o carregamento parcial do HTML, [DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded):

> O evento DOMContentLoaded é acionado quando o documento inicial HTML foi completamente carregado e analisado, sem aguardar por folhas de estilo, imagens, e subframes para encerrar o carregamento.

Fazes:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM completamente carregado e analisado");
    iframe.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Comment: Tem alguma diferença quanto carregar imagens ou apenas o html?

Comment: Coloquei, esse acrescento @GuilhermeLautert

Comment: Perfeito, completo :D

Comment: hehe de nada @GuilhermeLautert, ainda bem.